# CASCADE INSERT from Table A if key doesn't exist on Table B

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I have two tables which look like this:

```
products_tbl (product_id, product_manufacturer, product_name)
manufacturers_tbl (manufacturer_id, manufacturer_name)
```

Now in case a product_manufacturer is inserted into products_tbl which does NOT yet exist in manufacturers_tbl, I would like to automatically insert the respective key into manufacturers_tbl.

I already found quite a lot of old posts on the general topic of "cascading" inserts, but none of them wanted to integrate such logic.
Is it possible with mysql only, or would I have to write some more backend/php logic to accomplish this?

EDIT: 
If the above is not possible, I would like to know how to add a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT which throws an error if a product_manufacturer in products_tbl is added which has no equivalent manufacturer_name in manufacturers_tbl.

Comment: And where would you get the `manufacturer_name` from ? Practically, a manufacturer is supposed to be inserted first, and then the product(s) manufactured by that manufacturer.

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya Yes I know it doesnt make much sense, but the manufacturer_name would come from the product_manufacturer.
I wanted to make the usability of my addProducts form on my website better by allowing to add manufacturers which weren't explicitely added before on the separate addManufacturer form.

Comment: Purely MySQL way would be to use Triggers, but I would advise against it, as it can cause more headaches later. I would handle this in application code instead. Check if the manufacturer enter by the user (in a single form) already exists or not, and insert that accordingly. You can achieve that using `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Now use the `last_insert_id` to insert the product records

Comment: I feel I'm missing something here. You also have product_manufacturer table which will exist before you add to products_tbl? And you are not creating a manufactures_tbl at this point? But if product_manufacturer tbl does exist you want to create manufacturers_tbl (possibly)

Comment: @P.Salmon 
If I insert for example "Windows10" "Microsoft" into columns product_name and product_manufacturer from products table, while the manufacturers_tbl does not hold an entry "Microsoft" inside its manufacturer_name column, THEN I would like to have the entry "Microsoft" automatically created in the column manufacturer_name of the manufacturers_tbl.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough with a trigger but also easy to acquire junk.

```
drop table if exists products_tbl,manufacturers_tbl;

create table products_tbl (product_id int, product_manufacturer varchar(10), product_name varchar(10));
create table manufacturers_tbl (manufacturer_id int, manufacturer_name varchar(10));

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on products_tbl
for each row 
begin
    if not exists(select 1 from manufacturers_tbl where manufacturer_name = new.product_manufacturer) then
        insert into manufacturers_tbl(manufacturer_name) values (new.product_manufacturer);
    end if;
end $$
delimiter ;

insert into products_tbl values
(1,'microsoft','a'),
(2,'msoft','b'),
(3,'mcrosoft','c'),
(4,'microsoft','d');

select * from manufacturers_tbl;

+-----------------+-------------------+
| manufacturer_id | manufacturer_name |
+-----------------+-------------------+
|            NULL | microsoft         |
|            NULL | msoft             |
|            NULL | mcrosoft          |
+-----------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```